# Value too long for column "SCOPE BINARY(255) using JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa, h2

I am trying to work with some large text and store it to my H2 database.

This is the concerned variable:

```
@Lob
@Column
private String content;
```

When I am trying to store this text in my database, I am getting the following error:

```
Value too long for column "SCOPE BINARY(255)"
```

I already tried to annotate as `@Lob` but it doesn't help. How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like the Problem is in an other column

Comment: @Jens: If I remove this column or try ro add less characters it works without errors. I wonder why it creates the column `BINARY(255)` and not `TEXT` or `LONGTEXT`.

Comment: But why the error message Point to a column named `SCOPE`?

Comment: @Jens, thanks for pointing to the `SCOPE` column. This is what I did wrong. I forgot to add some `@OneToOne`-annotations. Many thanks for your support!